# environment variables OpenShift .NET Core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, openshift, .net-core

I try to deploy an ASP.NET Core 1.1 (Docker image) application on OpenShift online. The application generates a PDF file, but this needs write permission on a (temp) folder.
I've founded on the openshift documentation that there are folders to do this things: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#directory-variables

But I tried in my application to get the value of these environment variables but these are always empty. How can I get these in my code?
I tried these code:
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("$OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR")
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR")

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR` environment variable is from OpenShift 2 and not in OpenShift 3. The documentation you are linking is from OpenShift 2. In OpenShift 3 you can use `/tmp` if writing temporary files.